# Create long-term credentials for federated identity AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am using AWS services and I want to be able to create users through API and generate them long-term credentials to access aws resources(to access specific prefix in S3). One way to achieve it is with IAM users, but they are limited to 5000 users. Other option is to use federated identities or Cognito, but is there a way to create long-term access keys(I saw that access keys can be generated, but they are temporary via STS) for federated identities, because I could not find a way to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: IAM users are permanent, roles (including for federated users) are temporary. I'm afraid you can't change that. Your max temp session can be 12h.

Comment: Temporary credentials don't have to be all that painful. You can likely work out non-intrusive ways to refresh them every 12 hours. The key point about them being temporary is that if someone grabs your credentials a) they have a limited amount of time to do damage and b) there's a good chance that they're already expired.

Comment: If you are okay to spent a bit on this, then checkout https://aws.amazon.com/iam/partners/ .

Comment: @Siddharth Even if I spend time on iam partner, wouldn't I still have the problem with temporary credentials ?

Comment: Any luck with this? I have a similar situation. I want to create temporary (that last about 30 days) credentials that only have access to a specific directory in a specific S3 bucket. These users will be outside my organization and may be quite a lot so I don't want to create lots of IAM users, not sure how to do this.

Comment: No, I did not find a way to do it. We stopped using it anyways, so it is no longer a problem for us.